# How to get the record of employees who were joined in first quarter or first month

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to retrieve the records of employees who were joined in first quarter or in the first month. I have tried this but am not getting the right answer...

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE DOJ(date_created) = DOJ(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Please help me with this!

Comment: I can't find a `DOJ` function in the [list of MySQL functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/functions.html). Is that a user-defined function in your particular installation? If so, can you share its definition?

Comment: Also, do you mean "the first quarter of the current year or the first month of the current year"? In that case, isn't it the same as just "the first quarter of the current year"?

Comment: DOJ(date of joining) is name of column not a function in my case, since I'm new to mysql & learning the queries all my queries may be full of mistakes.apologies for that

Comment: First quarter of year 2015 & 1st month of year 2015

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question as clarified in a comment...

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE YEAR(table.doj) = 2015 AND QUARTER(table.doj) = 1
```

If instead you want "first quarter of prior year"...

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE YEAR(table.doj) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - 1 AND QUARTER(table.doj) = 1
```

In either case, note that there's no code to include the first month, because that's part of the first quarter.  However, if you wanted to make that explicit (at a slight performance hit), you could code it as follows...

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE YEAR(table.doj) = 2015 AND (QUARTER(table.doj) = 1
                                  OR MONTH(table.doj) = 1)
```

If you run into performance problems because you have a lot of records but only an index on `table.doj`, you could also write the query over an explicit date range...

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE table.doj >= '2015-01-01' AND table.doj <= '2015-03-31'
```